# Not getting correct value in structure

Tags: c

might be it's silly question but not getting what is wrong in my code.

I am writing simple command parser in which it will initialize appropriate parameters and call appropriate functions related to command code.

Ex.

```
char buffer[]="1123,13,46";
```

In above line `1123` is command code and rest of two tokens are parameters. In parser it will first find command code form command table and if command found then it will initialize structure of that command with above parameters.

Currently in my code i am successfully fetching correct command from command table and call that command's functions but failed to initialize the parameters with above values (13 and 46 here).Always getting `0`.

As per below code same thing i want in my command parser but little modification

```
typedef struct
{
    void *fields[2];

}tmpStruct;

typedef struct
{

    int x;
    int y;

}myStruct;

tmpStruct tmp_struct;

myStruct *getParams(tmpStruct *t_struct)
{
    myStruct *genericStruct = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));

        //setup the order of the fields in the handler
    t_struct->fields[0]=(void*)&genericStruct->x;

    t_struct->fields[1]=(void*)&genericStruct->y;

    return genericStruct;
}

void *fillValue(tmpStruct *t_struct)
{
    void *genericStruct;

    genericStruct = getParams(t_struct);

    *((int*)t_struct->fields[0])=12;
    *((int*)t_struct->fields[1])=13;

    return genericStruct;
}

void pritValue(myStruct *my_struct)
{
    printf("%d  %d\n",my_struct->x,my_struct->y);
}

int main()
{
    void *genericStruct;

    genericStruct = fillValue(&tmp_struct);

    pritValue(genericStruct);

    return 0;
}
```

Please find my working source file [here](http://pastebin.com/B89Qzjmc)

And header file [here](http://pastebin.com/4KMfW3qA)

Comment: Please post the relevant code or a minimal example here on this site.

Comment: @Lundin Sorry for long code but some minimal example have tried and it works but when i apply same logic to my code then it won't work. please see my updated question with working minimal code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are casting function pointers to types of functions that take different parameter types. Trying to make calls to functions through pointers like that is undefined behavior. Although you could potentially get away with calls that are similar - say, return `myStruct*` in place of `void*` pointer (although it's still undefined behavior), there is no way you could cast a function that takes an `int` and a `myStruct*` to a function type that takes an `int` and a variable list of arguments.

Changing your functions to the correct signatures to match `cmdTableStruct` table fixes this problem:

```
void *setParams(paramHandler_type *pHandler);
int printParams(int commandType,... );

static cmdTableStruct cmdTable[]=
{
 { 1123,setParams,printParams },
 //more command in same manner
};
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/mq8f0z)

Of course now you need to handle parameters from the `...` list individually using the functionality from the `<stdarg.h>` header.

Also, the way you dereference param handler when assigning values is incorrect - the index should be applied to `paramValue`, not to `pHandler`:

```
*((int*)pHandler->paramValue[j]) = (int)atoi(token);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer..but what output you get exactly output i got but i want those value in `int printParams(int commandType,...)` function. see `commandTable>process_command(commandType,genericMessageStruct);` call which ultimately call it.

Comment: @Jayesh You should either handle `...` correctly or use a generic `void*` as parameter (in your `cmdTableStruct`).

Comment: About the pointer types, this is C, not C++. Casting pointer is totally defined behavior, even with function types (as long as you make your calls properly). Many well known API, including linux natives and winapi are using this behavior (for callbacks and generic parameters).

Comment: @ElderBug I did not say that casting itself is incorrect, it's making calls without casting back that breaks. For instance, OP calls a function that takes an `int` and a struct pointer as if it took an `int` and a va_list.

Comment: yeah....`*((int*)pHandler->paramValue[j]) = (int)atoi(token);`  awesome catch..this is the correct ..thanks for saving my day. thanks again.